# converting database result into array in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and I am trying to make a login authentication system with the role of admin, moderator, and user.

My problem is that I am trying to set a condition on 'role' which is a column in database. But I don't know how to use and compare the value of column role.

I wrote the following code but I am getting error:

> [Severity: Error Message: Call to a member function result_array() on array]

My code is:

```html
<?php
// step no 4 create a new controller where form post after submission.
class verify extends CI_Controller{
     function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->helper('url');
         $this->load->model('user');
     }
    function login(){
        //step no 5 create a new method in verify controller 
     
       $username = $this->input->post('username');
       $userpass = $this->input->post('password');
       //step 9 take value back in answer variable from model and print message 
      $answer = $this->user->usergetdata($username,$userpass,'admin');   
     $data = $answer->result_array();


        if($answer){
            if($data[0]['role']=='admin'){
              redirect('admin_page');  
            }
            
            
        }else
        {
            echo "username or Password is wrong";
        }
    }
    
}

?>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Can we see your user model please?

Comment: Can you show us what is in your user get data method? Ideally you want to have a model method that simply returns an array of say login_status and role and test the logib_status and if that's happy then check the role type. Just some thoughts! Try to keep all your database stuff in the model. I see it's snuck out into your controller.

Comment: @router please `var_dump($answer);` and show this result.

Comment: here is model code @Blinkydamo


class user extends CI_Model{
     function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function usergetdata($username,$userpass,$role){
      
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('username',$username);
    $this->db->where('userpass',$userpass);
    
          $query= $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            return $query->result();
        }else 
        {
            return false;
        }
 
    }
}

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model

```
$res = $this->db->get(); 
return $res->result_array();
```

then apply

```
foreach($answer as $a)
{
  var_dump( $a );
}
```

use `$a` to get values

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($answer),true);
print_r($data);
```

used this your result convert in array format

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `->result()` in you model and then trying to call the result array from the controller.

Either remove the `->result();` from the `return $query->result();` in the model or remove the `->result_array()` from the controller.

Once you have called the script and used `->get()` you can only call one of the results at a time.  If you are likely to want to call different result parameters such as `->result()` and `->num_rows` on the same query result then just return the query to the controller and use `->result()` in the controller.

Hope this helps clear things up a little.

MODEL

```
class user extends CI_Model
{ 
  function __construct()
  { 
    parent::__construct(); 
  } 

  function usergetdata( $username,$userpass,$role )
  { 
    $this->db->select(); 
    $this->db->from( 'user' ); 
    $this->db->where( 'username',$username ); 
    $this->db->where( 'userpass',$userpass ); 
    $query= $this->db->get(); 
    if( $query->num_rows() == 1 )
    { 
      return $query; 
    }
    else
    { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
$answer = $this->user->usergetdata( $username,$userpass,'admin' );   
$data   = $answer->result_array();
```