# CodeIgniter 3.1.4 - PHP foreach not working the way I intend for $row elements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

What I want to do is append a list of all users and data relating to them to table rows using a PHP foreach, where this info is obtained from a database. The problem I am getting with this is the following error:

> [Severity: Error Message: Call to a member function result_array() on array]

I read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022043/converting-database-result-into-array-in-codeigniter) about this but it does not seem to fix my problem, as I then get a multitude of errors to do with trying to get a property from a non-object when removing the result_array() part from either the model or controller.

Here is the User.php Model:

```
Class User extends CI_Model
{
    function populateUsers()
    {
        $this->db->select('username, accessLevel, fullName');
        $this->db->from('users');

        $userquery = $this->db->get();

        if($userquery -> num_rows()>=1)
        {
            return $userquery->result_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

And here is a snippet from the AdminCP.php Controller:

```
    public function index()
    {   
    $this->load->helper(array('form')); // for user creation
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $aLevel = $session_data['accessLevel'];
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') && $aLevel == 'Admin')
    {                   
        $userResult = $this->user->populateUsers();
        if($userResult)
        {
            $user_array = array();
            foreach($userResult as $row)
            {
                $user_array = array(
                'username' => $row->username,
                'accessLevel' => $row->accessLevel,
                'fullName' => $row->fullName
                );

                $data['accessLevel'] = $session_data['accessLevel'];                
                $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];          
                $data['fullName'] = $session_data['fullName'];
                $data['userList'] = $user_array;                
                $this->load->view('admin_cp_view', $data);
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }   
    else
    {
    redirect('home', 'refresh');            
    session_write_close();
    }
}
```

And finally this is the section of the Admin_CP_View.php page that I want to display this information on:

```
<div class="well">
<h4>Manage users</h4>
<p>Select a user from the list to manage</p>
<table class="table">                           
                    <thead>                         
                            <tr>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Access Level</th>
                                <th>Full Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($userList->result_array() as $row)
                        { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['accessLevel'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['fullName'];?></td>                                 
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems. First, is not so much a problem as it is worthless code. A controller need not return a value because the Codeigniter does not expect one and won't pay any attention to it anyway.

Second, I have removed these lines from `index` because they appear to be unused in the view.

```
$data['accessLevel'] = $session_data['accessLevel'];
$data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
$data['fullName'] = $session_data['fullName'];
```

Here is a revised index function for the controller with the logic to return TRUE or FALSE removed.

```
public function index()
{
  $this->load->helper(array('form')); // for user creation
  $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
  $aLevel = $session_data['accessLevel'];
  if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') && $aLevel == 'Admin')
  {
    $data['userList'] = $this->user->populateUsers();
    $this->load->view('admin_cp_view', $data);
  }
  else
  {
    session_write_close();
    redirect('home', 'refresh');
  }
}
```

I would code the model's `populateUsers` method differently. First of all don't blindly use Query Builder. It's a great tool in certain circumstances. But your sql is so simple there is no point in running a whole lot of Query Build code for such a super easy db request.

See the code comments for the "why?" on the other changes.

```
Class User extends CI_Model
{
  function populateUsers()
  {
    $userquery = $this->db->query("Select usernam, accessLevel, fullName from users");

    if($userquery->num_rows() > 0)
    {
      return $userquery->result_array();
    }
  //{
    //else
    //you do not need the else because if there were rows the method has returned 
    //and the next line will never be executed. 

    //On the other hand, if there are no rows then this line WILL execute
    return array(); //Return empty array so that the view won't try to run foreach on a boolean
//  }
  }
```

Then in the view the code for your `<table>` is this

```
<table class="table">                           
  <thead>                         
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Access Level</th>
      <th>Full Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($userList as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['accessLevel']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['fullName']; ?></td>                                 
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This will write one row to the table for each item in `$userList`.

I think you may not have correctly made the changes I suggested on my first attempt to answer. You probably got multiple page loads because you had a call to `load->view` inside of a `foreach` loop. Now only the table rows should repeat.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it still doesn't work and actually causes the page to repeat itself over and over with the different rows that are retrieved from the database: (http://prntscr.com/esbril). It is basically not appending the data to a row, and instead actually looks like it is generating a whole new page.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing what you describe and the screen shot you link to does not show anything unusual.

Comment: Ah yes I should have been clearer. Basically what is happening is for every record the foreach retrieves, it is appending this as a whole other page but showing a different row of values on that table on the "other" page. Here is another screenshot which should clarify what I mean: http://prntscr.com/esehi1 (note that i zoomed it out manually just so that you could see)

Comment: I've done a total rewrite of my answer. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your patience with this, it's working as intended now!

Answer (score 0):

## Edit in your AdminCP.php

```
 public function index()
    {   
    $this->load->helper(array('form')); // for user creation
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $aLevel = $session_data['accessLevel'];
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') && $aLevel == 'Admin')
    {                   
        $userResult = $this->user->populateUsers();
        if($userResult)
        {

                $this->load->view('admin_cp_view', $userResult);
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }   
    else
    {
    redirect('home', 'refresh');            
    session_write_close();
    }
}
```

## Edit in your Admin_CP_View.php

```
<div class="well">
<h4>Manage users</h4>
<p>Select a user from the list to manage</p>
<table class="table">                           
                    <thead>                         
                            <tr>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Access Level</th>
                                <th>Full Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($userResult as $row)
                        { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['accessLevel'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['fullName'];?></td>                                 
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

This may helps you.. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Change your user model to this:

```
Class User extends CI_Model
{
    function populateUsers()
    {
        $this->db->select('username, accessLevel, fullName');
        $this->db->from('users');

        $userquery = $this->db->get();

        if($userquery->num_rows() >= 1)
        {
            return $userquery->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```